# Pull FIRST result from JSON decoded data in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a script:

```
$json_url = "https://blockchain.info/ticker";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$json=str_replace('},

]',"}

]",$json);
$data = json_decode($json);

echo "$" . ($data->USD->last);
```

This works perfect!

Now I have a second version of this:

```
$json_url3 = "https://blockchain.info/da/unconfirmed-transactions?format=json";
$json3 = file_get_contents($json_url3);
$json3=str_replace('},

]',"}

]",$json3);
$data3 = json_decode($json3);
echo "Latest hash: " . ($data3->txs->hash) . "<br>";
```

Why does the send script not work? I have a `$json2` running without any issues with another API call as well.

Comment: its a valid JSON, may I ask why are you replacing the chars??

Comment: If OP has to replace `},]` it's not a valid json)

Comment: It could be the case that the result from the first URL is valid JSON and the second one isn't. Like @u_mulder said, if you're having to do some editing to the resulting string, then it likely isn't valid json. You should be able to just call json_decode on the response if the datatype is json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `txs` is an array of objects.

Your last line should be written as:

```
echo "Latest hash: " . ($data3->txs[0]->hash) . "<br>";
```

It outputs:

```
Latest hash: fd37b1ddfbe08d485a62bb3aeb7c9088e7dd3a352ac9e9e8eb6f170a9b4210cd
```

Comment: echo "Latest hash: " . ($data3->txs[0]->hash) . "<br>"; This solved the question :)

Comment: You should mark Inigo's answer as the correct answer if it properly answered the question you were asking.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked :)

```
$json_url3 = "https://blockchain.info/da/unconfirmed-transactions?format=json";
$json3 = file_get_contents($json_url3);
$json3=str_replace('},

]',"}

]",$json3);
$data3 = json_decode($json3);
echo "Latest hash: " . ($data3->txs[0]->hash) . "<br>";
```

txs[0]

I assume the issue was that there is more than 1(one) element in the array